# How to set rectangle border for custom type UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to set an image as the background of a custom UIButton. I was able to set a background image for the "rounded rect" UIButton in interface builder, but now the borders have vanished. Is there any way to retain the borders? Also, I would like to make the borders show up rectangular instead of rounded.

Comment: A little more information perhaps? Are you implementing -drawRect: at all? What sort of custom button are we talking about? Have you tried setting its background using an image (that's what most folks will probably be doing), or are you specifically looking for rectangle-drawing methods?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. Are you trying to draw a custom border? Set the size of your button? Please give us some more details.

Comment: fine, I am trying to set an image as background of UIButton. I did this by setting background image for "rounded rect" UIButton in interface builder. but borders are vanished, Is there any way to retain the borders? also I need to make borders as rect instead of "rounded rect".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a background image in a button, the button outlines go away.  Include them in your image, if you need different sizes look at the UIImage

`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`

method.

Answer (score 43):

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> // don't forget to add this in your file
    CALayer * layer = [yourUIButton layer];
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [layer setCornerRadius:0.0]; //when radius is 0, the border is a rectangle
    [layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
```

i know this is an old question, but still i would like to post my answer here. since i was looking for answer but got this resolved myself in an easy way.

Comment: really no way to do this without core anim?

Comment: For those who didn't see @TylerJames addition below: Note that you need to import the QuartzCore framework for this to work.

Answer (score 17):

Check out the `cornerRadius`, `borderWidth` and `borderColor` properties of `CALayer`.  These properties are new as of iPhone OS 3.0.

You probably want to subclass `UIButton` and then set these properties in the constructor.  Your button has a layer property you can access to set these border properties.

Here's an example:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

    [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:0.7] CGColor]];
}

return self;
}
```

Comment: In 2.2.1 I would go with something along the lines of what Kendall is suggesting below.

Is this a new application?  If so, I'm pretty sure that Apple will only be approving apps that are compatible with iPhone OS 3.0 from now on.

Comment: Yes, It is a new application. Since Apple is going to approve only OS 3.0 compatible applications, new applications may not work with previous OS versions. Even though OS 3.0 upgrade is free, some of them may not willing to upgrade. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Because 3.0 is free (actually $10 for iPod Touch) the financial barrier for users to upgrade is pretty low.  With all the new OS features and associated apps that will be developed, I think most users will upgrade to 3.0 fairly quickly.

With those assumptions in place, I'd rather focus my time on improving my user experience and adding new features.  I guess I want to keep my support/maintenance activities to a minimum as long as it doesn't greatly affect my users.

Comment: Thank you, let us hope most of the users will do upgrade.

Comment: Historically, the vast majority of users have upgraded... after all, you're not worrying about targeting 2.1 to capture all 12 users who haven't upgraded from that version.

Answer (score 8):

You could also "User Defined Runtime Attributes" in IB to set rounded corners like done in image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBkuB.png

Answer (score 7):

I'd just like to add to the answers provided by nanshi and Jonathan.

In order to access the `border` and `cornerRadius` properties of the layer you will first need to import the QuartzCore framework.

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Otherwise you will not be able to access the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the border properties on the CALayer by accessing the layer property of the button.

First, add Quartz

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Set properties:

```
[[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
```