# How to add a button border - ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an application. How can I add a button border. I tried googling, but nothing works for me. can any one help me. The button in my application is `IBAction` not `IBOutlet`.

viewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOneMoved;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonTwoMoved;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonThreeMoved;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonFourMoved;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonFiveMoved;

- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonTwo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonThree:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonFour:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonFive:(id)sender;


@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)buttonTwo:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)buttonThree:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)buttonFour:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)buttonFive:(id)sender {

}
@end
```

Comment: In my application I want to change the buttonOne border color how can I change?

Comment: There is one line that confuses me, this one `"The button in my application is IBAction not IBOutlet."` Clearly the button in your application is `IBOutlet` as you can see on the likes of this line `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOneMoved;` (Which is correct). So not sure what you mean by this line. Please can you clarify?

Comment: Actually I want to set the border of `buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour,buttonFive.` These are not `IBOutlet`. These are `IBAction`.

Comment: But where are the properties for `buttonOne, buttonTwo etc`? This `- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender;` is **NOT** declaring a button it is a method declaration so `buttonOne, buttonTwo etc` don't even exist according to your code.

Comment: @Bhargav you should [accept some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Your last 5 questions have multiple answers but none of them are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, a button can be ***both*** an "`IBOutlet`" and point to an "`IBAction`".

But if you want to highlight the button that's been pressed, you could do something like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender {
    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    [[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    [myButton setNeedsLayout];

}
```

The [answer for which I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162411/how-to-create-border-in-uibutton), or [you could do this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854306/how-to-set-rectangle-border-for-custom-type-uibutton).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to tell you how to tell the button to force update, which is the "`setNeedsLayout`" call.

Comment: Where should I write `setNeedsLayout` ?

Comment: Actually It works when I click the button. but I want the border at initial

Comment: then you are going to need to connect your buttons to "`IBOutlets`" and call those same methods then.

Comment: How can I connect ?
give the whole procedure

Comment: [These tutorials at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've bind all buttons in your view.

in `viewDidLoad` write below code for all button

```
[buttonOneMoved.layer setBorderWidth:3.0f];
[buttonOneMoved.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
```

Suggestion : if you don't want to outlet your button in Xib and make all button with blue border then take all subviews of your self.view. consider your buttons are in self.view. write below code in `viewDidLoad`

```
for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [btn.layer setBorderWidth:3.0f];
        [btn.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to set the border for buttonOne, `buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour,buttonFive`. These are not IBOutlet. These are IBAction. your code works fine for `buttonOneMoved` but it gives an error on `buttonOne.`

Comment: @Bhargav first you should learn iOS basics. what is IBOutlets and IBActions.